# NIL value decoding nested JSON - SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm getting `nil` while decoding a "fairly simple" nested JSON, what am I missing here?

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

The `NetworkController` part (along with the whole `ContentView`) works perfectly with "plain" JSONs (i.e. `{"greetings": "hi"}`), yet I'm still getting `nil` with nested JSON Structures

Here's my JSON:

**index.json**

```
{
  "products": {
    "pasta": 81.22,
    "pizza": 13.81,
    "apples": 0,
    "sausages": 2.36,
    "potatoes": 0.55,
    "cucmbers": 2.06,
    "oranges": 0
  }
}
```

Here's my Code:

**DataStruct.swift**

```
struct ProductWrapper: Decodable {
    var products: Product
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    var pasta: Double
    var pizza: Double
    var apples: Double
    var sausages: Double
    var potatoes: Double
    var cucmbers: Double
    var oranges: Double
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

class ProductsList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prods: ProductWrapper? = nil
    func fetchProducts() {
        NetworkController.fetchProducts { prods in
            self.prods = prods
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var DecodedProducts = ProductsList()

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            HStack{
                Text("Pasta: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.pasta)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.red)
            }

            HStack{
                Text("Pizza: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.pizza)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.blue)
            }

            HStack{
                Text("Apples: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.apples)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.green)
            }

        }.padding()
    }
}
```

**NetworkManager.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct NetworkController {
    static func fetchProducts(completion: @escaping ((ProductWrapper) -> Void)) {
        if let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:1234/index.json") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, resp, err) in
                do {
                    if let products = data {
                        let prods = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductWrapper.self, from: products)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            completion(prods)
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Error Found")
                    }
                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem;

That was just a dumb me...

Forgot to call the `fetchProducts()` in the `onAppear` *facepalm*

```
.onAppear{
self.DecodedProducts.fetchProducts()
}
```

Here's the correct code:

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

class ProductsList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prods: ProductWrapper? = nil
    func fetchProducts() {
        NetworkController.fetchProducts { prods in
            self.prods = prods
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var DecodedProducts = ProductsList()



    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            HStack{
                Text("Pasta: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.pasta ?? 0)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.red)
            }

            HStack{
                Text("Pizza: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.pizza ?? 0)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.blue)
            }

            HStack{
                Text("Apples: ")
                Text(String("\(self.DecodedProducts.prods?.products.apples ?? 0)")).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.green)
            }

        }.onAppear{
            self.DecodedProducts.fetchProducts()
            }
        }
    }
```